# Rotate Video- Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?)

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, video-editing

I am using below command to rotate video-

```
{"-y", "-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000, "-i", inputPath, "-vf", "transpose=" + type,"-c:a", "copy", outputPath}
```

I am getting below failure message in Android Oreo-

> "ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers\n
>   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)\n  configuration: --target-os=linux
>   --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
>   --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot
>   --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include
>   -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib
>   -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=\n  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103\n  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102\n  libavformat    57. 25.100 /
>   57. 25.100\n  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101\n  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100\n  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100\n  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101\n  libpostproc    54.  0.100 /
>   54.  0.100\nInput #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Download/dolbycanyon.3gp':\n  Metadata:\n
>   major_brand     : 3gp4\n    minor_version   : 512\n
>   compatible_brands: isomiso23gp4\n  Duration: 00:00:38.07, start:
>   0.006250, bitrate: 402 kb/s\n    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h263 (s263 / 0x33363273), yuv420p, 704x576 [SAR 12:11 DAR 4:3], 384 kb/s, 29.97
>   fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)\n    Metadata:\n
>   handler_name    : VideoHandler\n    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: amr_nb
>   (samr / 0x726D6173), 8000 Hz, mono, flt, 12 kb/s (default)\n
>   Metadata:\n      handler_name    : SoundHandler\n[libx264 @
>   0xf64e5400] using SAR=11/12\n[libx264 @ 0xf64e5400] using cpu
>   capabilities: none!\n[libx264 @ 0xf64e5400] profile High, level
>   3.1\n[libx264 @ 0xf64e5400] 264 - core 148 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options:
>   cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1
>   psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1
>   8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2
>   threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1
>   interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2
>   b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250
>   keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf
>   mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40
>   aq=1:1.00\n[mp4 @ 0xf64a8600] Could not find tag for codec amr_nb in
>   stream #1, codec not currently supported in container\nOutput #0, mp4,
>   to '/storage/emulated/0/Movies/rotate_video4.mp4':\n  Metadata:\n
>   major_brand     : 3gp4\n    minor_version   : 512\n
>   compatible_brands: isomiso23gp4\n    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100\n
>   Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021),
>   yuv420p, 576x704 [SAR 11:12 DAR 3:4], q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn,
>   29.97 tbc (default)\n    Metadata:\n      handler_name    : VideoHandler\n      encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libx264\n    Side
>   data:\n      unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)\n    Stream
>   0:1(und): Audio: amr_nb (samr / 0x726D6173), 8000 Hz, mono, 12 kb/s (default)\n    Metadata:\n      handler_name    : SoundHandler\nStream
>   mapping:\n  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h263 (native) -> h264 (libx264))\n 
>   Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)\nCould not write header for output file #0
>   (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument\n"

Why am i getting this error and how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MP4 does not officially support amr_nb audio. To force it anyway,

```
{"-y", "-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000, "-i", inputPath, "-vf", "transpose=" + type,"-c:a", "copy", "-atag","samr", outputPath}
```

But recommend you save to .3gp instead.

Alternatively, you can re-encode audio by dropping `"-c:a", "copy"`

Comment: Will re-encoding audio(by dropping "-c:a", "copy") doesn't uses  amr_nb audio?And will it maintains the quality of audio?

Comment: Yes, aac codec will be used and quality will be around the same.